# Is it possible to build a random forest with model based trees i.e., `mob()` in partykit package

Tags: r, random-forest, party, ctree

I'm trying to build a random forest using model based regression trees in partykit package. I have built a model based tree using `mob()` function with a user defined `fit()` function which returns an object at the terminal node.

In partykit there is `cforest()` which uses only `ctree()` type trees. I want to know if it is possible to modify `cforest()` or write a new function which builds random forests from model based trees which returns objects at the terminal node. I want to use the objects in the terminal node for predictions. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit: The tree I have built is similar to the one here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059827/14168775

How do I build a random forest using a tree similar to the one in above answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, there is no canned solution for general model-based forests using `mob()` although most of the building blocks are available. However, we are currently reimplementing the backend of `mob()` so that we can leverage the infrastructure underlying `cforest()` more easily. Also, `mob()` is quite a bit slower than `ctree()` which is somewhat inconvenient in learning forests.

The best alternative, currently, is to use `cforest()` with a custom `ytrafo`. These can also accomodate model-based transformations, very much like the scores in `mob()`. In fact, in many situations `ctree()` and `mob()` yield very similar results when provided with the same score function as the transformation.

A worked example is available in this conference presentation:

> Heidi Seibold, Achim Zeileis, Torsten Hothorn (2017).
> "Individual Treatment Effect Prediction Using Model-Based Random Forests."
> Presented at Workshop "Psychoco 2017 - International Workshop on Psychometric Computing",
> WU Wirtschaftsuniversität Wien, Austria.
> URL [https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/papers/Psychoco-2017.pdf](https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/%7Ezeileis/papers/Psychoco-2017.pdf)

The special case of model-based random forests for individual treatment effect prediction was also implemented in a dedicated package `model4you` that uses the approach from the presentation above and is available from CRAN. See also:

> Heidi Seibold, Achim Zeileis, Torsten Hothorn (2019).
> "`model4you`: An R Package for Personalised Treatment Effect Estimation."
> *Journal of Open Research Software*, **7**(17), 1-6.
> [doi:10.5334/jors.219](https://doi.org/10.5334/jors.219)

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. I have another clarification regarding the package. Is it possible to merge several `mob()` tree objects to form a forest? I want to use `varimp()` function and it requires a forest object but I have several different tree objects generated using `mob()`.

Comment: Not out of the box because this requires a proper prediction based on suitability weighted model fits.